# Gitlab CI/CD unexpected behavior

Tags: angular, gitlab, yaml, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

i'm new to CD with gitlab and i wanted to do some test.
My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
image: node:latest
before_script:
  - npm install -g @angular/cli
  - npm install
  - ng build --prod
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install lftp
build:
  script:
    - lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no;open $FTP_HOST ; user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASSWORD; mirror -X .* -X .*/ --reverse --verbose dist/ $FTP_ROOT; bye"
```

The code works and the files are sent to the server correctly.
The problem is that all the files are placed under a subdirectory created by the script.
The subdirectory has the same name of the gitlab repository.
The server root directory is not empty (maybe can this cause the problem?).

What i'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What's wrong?  What is the behavior you expect?  Which script are you referring to when you say all the files are placed under a subdirectory created by the script.  Why is this a problem? When you say "The server root directory is not empty", which server are you referring to?

Comment: @AlekseyTsalolikhin i expect that all the files will be placed in the root directory, not in a subdirectory. for "the script" i mean the yml in the question. This is a problem because i need my angular app in www.example.com not in www.example.com/subdirectory. For "server" i mean the server where i'm uploading the files. This subdirectory is created during the upload, and i don't know how to prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `mirror -X .* -X .*/ --reverse --verbose dist/ $FTP_ROOT` to `mirror -X .* -X .*/ --reverse --verbose dist/subdirectory $FTP_ROOT` to place your angular app in www.example.com not in www.example.com/subdirectory (assuming `$FTP_ROOT` is the FTP server root -- I don't actually see where that is set).